# How to add multiple possibilities to one variable in an if statement

Tags: if-statement

How do i add multiple possibilities to one variable in an if statement

if Begin == "Yes" or Begin == "yes"

Comment: Please phrase your question more clearly. Post us some code in a real language and tell us what is not working to your satisfaction.

Comment: Depends on language: C `if(strcmp(Begin, "Yes") || strcmp(Begin , "yes"))` java `if(Begin.equals("Yes") || Begin.equals("yes"))`

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

What language ?
It could be something lukę this :

If (begin == "Yes" || begin == "yes)

In C# :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you asking but for example in qt

```
const QString lowered = Begin.toLower();
if( "yes"==lowered )
{
//do something
}
```